# Javascript event binding persistence

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

If you have a HTML element that is constantly rendered/destroyed, do the Javascript event bindings to the HTML persist, or is it necessary to bind/unbind events as part of the creation/destruction cycle?

I'm using D3 to generate a map of the counties in the US.  In addition, I'm generating a tooltip overlay that includes buttons upon a click event for a valid selection.

Part of the click event handler where I bind the HTML of the template to the tooltip element and then bind the Javascript event handlers to said HTML

```
thisObj._tooltip.template = template : "<div id = 'tooltip_template'>" + 
            "<div class = 'county_data'></div>" +
            "<img src = '/static/images/delete.png' width = '28' height = '28' class = 'delete_logo' id = 'close_tooltip' />" +
            "<button id = 'add_prospective_market' class = 'tooltip_button'>Prospective Market</button>" +
            "<button id = 'add_market' class = 'tooltip_button'>Market County</button>" +
            "<button id = 'remove_market' class = 'tooltip_button'>Remove Market</button></div>"

thisObj._tooltip.tooltip.html(thisObj._tooltip.template)
  .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
  .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 50) + "px")
  .style("pointer-events" , "auto")
  .style("width", "400px")
  .style("height", "150px");

$(".county_data").text(d.name + ", " + d.properties.StateCode);

addTooltipHandlers();

thisObj._tooltip.tooltip.transition()
 .duration(800)
 .style("opacity", 1);
```

I bind the event handlers to the elements via

```
var addTooltipHandlers = function(){
  $("#add_market").on("click", function(){
    console.log("Adding new Market")
  });
  
  $("#add_prospective_market").on("click", function(){
    console.log("Adding new Prospective market")
  });
  
  $("#remove_market").on("click", function(){
     console.log("Removing this market")
  });
  
  $("#close_tooltip")
    .on("mouseover", function(){
      $(this).css({"border-color" : "red", "opacity" : 1});
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(){
      $(this).css({"border-color" : "black", "opacity" : 0.5});
    })
    .on("click", function(){
      console.log("Closing tooltip");

      d3.selectAll($("#" + thisObj._tooltip.county))
        .style("fill", thisObj._currentCounty.color);

      thisObj._tooltip.tooltip.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .style("pointer-events", "none");

      thisObj._tooltip.open = false;
      removeTooltipHandlers();
   });
}
```

Since a tooltip is only visible on the screen until a close event is registered, and then it is destroyed, once an event listener is bound to an element, does that binding persist when that element is destroyed and re-created?

Comment: An event handler is bound to the DOM element. If the element is destroyed, so are the event handlers (or at least the binding).

Comment: So there is no possibility for unattached event handlers to exist if the DOM element is destroyed?

Comment: @Jason check my answer, you need to use event delegation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order for event handlers to persist you have to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) in jquery

instead of

```
$(...).on(event, handler)
```

use

```
$(...).on(event, selector, handler)
```

for instance

```
$('body').on('click','a.saveButton', saveHandler)
```

This way you attach event handler to body element instead of actual element you can destroy or add to DOM. So handlers will work untill your turn them off.

Even better for all global event handlers you can use event namespaces, like:

```
$('body').on('click.app','a.saveButton', saveHandler)
$('body').on('click.app','a.addButton', addHandler)
```

This will allow you to `off` all of them together:

```
$('body').off('.app')
```

UPDATE: very simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/wsxcL8mn/)  to show event delegation.

Comment: Will the event delegation modification work if I declare the binding before creating the DOM element?

Comment: @Jason yes, that is one of the reason to use it in the first place.

Comment: Actually you declare event binding for 'body' element and it will catch all the clicks from page (except for the ones for which stopPropagation was called somewhere) And on every click jQuery will check does the original element fit the given selector (a.savebutton).  For this reason it is better to bind handler to closest persistent element instead of body.

Comment: @AntonU. that is what I did in the fiddle.