# Why would this JS fire on a form partial rendered on 1 page but not another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a `posts.js` file that looks like this:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

    var toggleSidebar = $(".togglesidebar");
    var primary = $("#primary");
    var secondary = $("#secondary");

    toggleSidebar.on("click", function(){

        if(primary.hasClass("col-sm-9")){
            primary.removeClass("col-sm-9");
            primary.addClass("col-sm-12");
            secondary.css('display', 'none');
        }
        else {
            primary.removeClass("col-sm-12");
            primary.addClass("col-sm-9");
            secondary.css('display', 'inline-block');
        }
    }); 
};

var counter = function(event) {
    var fieldValue = $(this).val();
    var wc = fieldValue.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
    var regex = /\s+/gi;
    var $wcField;
    var maxWc;

    if ($(this)[0] === $('#post_title')[0]) {
      $wcField = $('#wordCountTitle');
      maxWc = 7;
    } else {
      $wcField = $('#wordCountBody');
      maxWc = 150;
    }

    $wcField.html(wc);
    $wcField.toggleClass('over-limit', wc > maxWc);
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
    $('#post_title, #body-field').on('change keyup paste', counter);
});
```

In my `application.html.erb` page, I have this:

```
<div id="secondary" class="col-sm-3 sidebar" style="display: none;">
    <aside>
      <div class="about">
        <h4>Submit Report</h4>
            <%= render "posts/form" %>
        </div>
    </aside> 
</div>  <!-- /#secondary -->
```

And when I toggle this div, and the `_form` partial is displayed, the JS works fine in those fields.

But if I go to `posts/new` or `/posts/:id/edit`, it doesn't.

Even though if I check the source of that page, I see the `post.js` included there.

What could be causing this?

**Edit 1**

I am using Turbolinks, if that matters.

**Edit 2**

I tried this, per suggestions in the Answers:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

    // This is the Sidebar toggle functionality
    var toggleSidebar = $(".togglesidebar");
    var primary = $("#primary");
    var secondary = $("#secondary");

    $(document).on("click", ".togglesidebar", function(){       

        if(primary.hasClass("col-sm-9")){
            primary.removeClass("col-sm-9");
            primary.addClass("col-sm-12");
            secondary.css('display', 'none');
        }
        else {
            primary.removeClass("col-sm-12");
            primary.addClass("col-sm-9");
            secondary.css('display', 'inline-block');
        }
    }); 
};
```

But that hasn't worked.

The key issue I am having a problem with is the 'counters', i.e. `#wordCountTitle` and `#wordCountBody` don't work on my `/posts/new` even though they work on the `posts/index` when `.toggleSidebar` is activated.

Comment: Have you included the file in your application.js file under app/assets/javascripts?  Sounds like an asset pipeline problem.

Comment: I have `//= require_tree .` in my `application.js`. That should cover everything in my JS directory no?

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: @John Yes. I am for sure.

Comment: Turbolinks is known to cause issues with loading JavaScript between pages. Which portion of the JavaScript isn't getting triggered? Try adding `$(document).on('page:load', ready);` after `$(document).ready(ready);`

Comment: @John I did. Scroll down in the middle portion of my code and you will see it. Or are you saying I should do something different?

Comment: Which part of the code doesn't work when you change pages? The `ready` part or the `counter` part or both?

Comment: The `counter` function. The `ready` function works, most of the time. It doesn't work whenever Turbolinks kicks in though, i.e. when I go from one page to another though...so there is that. Not sure if the two are related.

Comment: what is the version of jQuery you're using ? Starting from 1.8 '`ready` in `on()` is deprecated as per the official [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to invoke some callback every time a page is loaded by turbo links, just use `$(document).on('page:load', callback)` as `page:load` is the event triggered by turbo links once your page of interest is loaded. Also you're trying to register `counter` function as callback on these `#post_title, #body-field` elements, do they come as part of every page you're loading ? Also as you're using id-selectors, you need to make sure that there are no other elements with same ids, left overs from previous load. Can you confirm on that ?

Comment: dumb question:the regex  variable shouldn't be places above the wc variable?

Comment: Hey @marcamillion, please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754227/re-rendering-specific-js-file-with-turbolinks-enabled

Answer (score 7):

Instead of binding directly to the element's onclick which needs careful handling of Turbolinks events, you can use an event handler on the document, try changing the direct event

```
toggleSidebar.on("click", function(){
```

to the delegated event

```
$(document).on("click", ".togglesidebar", function(){
```

When you modify the DOM dynamically (as when Turbolinks replaces it) if you use a direct event then you would need to re-assign it.

For a detailed explanation see http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

---

The same that goes for the first function stands for the second. Also, with delegated events the "ready" check becomes unnecessary. With this in mind, your code would become:

```
$(document).on("click", ".togglesidebar", function(){

    var primary = $("#primary");
    var secondary = $("#secondary");

    if(primary.hasClass("col-sm-9")){
        primary.removeClass("col-sm-9");
        primary.addClass("col-sm-12");
        secondary.css('display', 'none');
    }
    else {
        primary.removeClass("col-sm-12");
        primary.addClass("col-sm-9");
        secondary.css('display', 'inline-block');
    }

}); 

$(document).on('change keyup paste', '#post_title, #body-field', function () {
    var fieldValue = $(this).val();
    var wc = fieldValue.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
    var regex = /\s+/gi;
    var $wcField;
    var maxWc;

    if ($(this)[0] === $('#post_title')[0]) {
      $wcField = $('#wordCountTitle');
      maxWc = 7;
    } else {
      $wcField = $('#wordCountBody');
      maxWc = 150;
    }

    $wcField.html(wc);
    $wcField.toggleClass('over-limit', wc > maxWc);
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. To be clear, I replaced this line: ` toggleSidebar.on("click", function(){` with this line: `$(document).on("click", ".togglesidebar", function(){` within the `ready()` function. Also, the issue is primarily on the word & character counter. That is what is not working on my `/posts/new/` page. This change doesn't fix that.

Comment: For some reason, the counter still doesn't work on that page, even with your new code. But it works on the original partial though.

Answer (score 1):

I am using something like this on one of my projects, had the same problem hope it helps:

```
window.onLoad = function(callback) {
  $(document).ready(callback);
  $(document).on('page:load', callback);
};
```

and then wrap up my functions with onLoad, something like

```
onLoad(function() {
  counter()
});
```

The onLoad function binds the ready event and the turbolink page:load event

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Or rather, my implementation doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

when you do

```
$("selector").on("click", function(){});
```

you actually bind the selector to the click event.

White if you use

```
$(document).on("click", "selector", function(){});
```

You bind the click event to the document, which after the click checks if the clicked element was the selector you used. if yes, it executes the function. So you should use the second approach whenever binding events on dynamic elements.

I hope that answers the question of "why"

Comment: I tried adjusting this, see my comment on agios's answer, and it didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Long time I don't work with jQuery, but since I got here: If you have more than one element with the selector ".sidebar", I believe you'll need to use ".each" to bind the function to all elements that match that selector on the dom.

For the reference go here http://api.jquery.com/each/

Hope this helps, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look on Turbolinks, and it does what I thought it did: It loads the HTML content of a link inside a container on the main page. Problem is, anything it loads is agnostic of whatever events and functions you have declared when the main page loaded, so indeed, after the first click, the selector on the HTML it has just loaded won't have the click event attributed to it (it was not on the DOM when you did the binding).

Possible solution: I did a little research on the .live() method, but is has been deprecated, so I recommend doing something like this:

$('body').on('click','a.saveButton', saveHandler)

Binding closer to the element you need will, it seems, will assure that whatever Turbolinks loads inside the body will get the bindings you have declared.

There is a more detailed answer here: [Javascript event binding persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032597/javascript-event-binding-persistence)

The documentation for the .live hook is here: http://api.jquery.com/live/#typefn

I used to have the same architecture on my web pages back in the day, and I did run on a problem similar to yours.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Should it work.. make sure:

1. Nothing id conflict.
2. Your html structure, maybe you forgot put value in your post.
3. Maybe wrong path posts.js, open with CTRL+U and then click post.js what is showing your code, if there so it's ok.

I try like this, it's ok(dummy):

```js
$(document).on("click", ".togglesidebar", function(){

    var primary = $("#primary");
    var secondary = $("#secondary");

    if(primary.hasClass("col-sm-9")){
        primary.removeClass("col-sm-9");
        primary.addClass("col-sm-12");
        secondary.css('display', 'none');
    }
    else {
        primary.removeClass("col-sm-12");
        primary.addClass("col-sm-9");
        secondary.css('display', 'inline-block');
    }
 
 

}); 

$(document).on('change keyup paste', '#post_title, #body-field', function () {
    
    var fieldValue = $(this).val();
    var wc = fieldValue.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
 
 console.log(wc);
 
    var regex = /\s+/gi;
    var $wcField;
    var maxWc;

    if ($(this)[0] === $('#post_title')[0]) {
      $wcField = $('#wordCountTitle');
      maxWc = 7;
    } else {
      $wcField = $('#wordCountBody');
      maxWc = 150;
    }

    $wcField.html(wc);
    $wcField.toggleClass('over-limit', wc > maxWc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="togglesidebar">Toogle</div>
<div id="wordCountTitle"></div>
<div id="wordCountBody"></div>
<div id="primary">
<div id="secondary" class="col-sm-3 sidebar" style="display: none;">
    <aside>
      <div class="about">
        <h4>Submit Report</h4>
            <input type="text" id="body-field"/>
        </div>
    </aside> 
</div>  <!-- /#secondary --> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly with Js problems involving Turbolinks the best way to have it work efficiently is to install jquery rails gem, add // require jquery-Turbolinks  and then remove //require turbolinks in your Js file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the ids you are passing on the jQuery selectors are unique. If that page/partial is loaded without a postback, you should use

```
//document or selector that does not get removed
var primary = $(document).find('#primary'); 
var secondary = $(document).find('#secondary');
```

this, with

```
$(document).click('eventName', 'contextSelector', function)
```

should help resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If `#post_title` and `#body-field` are created dynamically you'll need to change:

```
$('#post_title, #body-field').on('change keyup paste', counter);
```

To this:

```
$(document).on('change keyup paste', '#post_title, #body-field', counter);
```

You'll need to delegate your events to elements that exist on page load (the `document` itself, in this case) when targeting elements that don't exist when the page is loaded (probably `#post_title` and `#body-field`).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `$('#wordCountTitle')` and `$('#wordCountBody')` on `/posts/new`, have you tried just typing in either of them at the console? It's possible that the view for `/posts/new` is different to your index and is missing those ids (or you made them classes or some other transposition happened).

I was having all kinds of issues with Turbolinks and jquery so a few suggestions on how I would go about trying to fix your problems:

1. Use `gem 'turbolinks'` to include it. Follow the instructions and do it the Ruby (gems) way rather than the PHP way.
2. Using Turbolinks means that`$(document).ready` doesn't fire when a new 'page' loads. The solution is to use: `$(document).on('page:load', ready)` along with `$(document).ready(ready)`. The `page:load` event is the Turbolinks version of the `ready` event.
3. Others have suggested it but I've found it incredibly valuable in my rails app: Rather than binding events directly to selectors `$("a").click(/* function */)`, binding to the document means that when Turbolinks loads a new page, the document binding survives the page load: `$(document).on('click', 'a.particularAnchor', particularAnchorClicked)`

With your specific code in mind, I would change this:

```
$('#post_title, #body-field').on('change keyup paste', counter);
```

To

```
$(document).on('change keyup paste', '#post_title, #body-field', counter);
```

It also seems to me that in your `counter` function you have mixed the following two lines up (`regex` needs to be defined first)

```
var wc = fieldValue.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
var regex = /\s+/gi;
```