# Confusing scoping upon reload of partial in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, scope

I'm building a simple todo that features task priority, I want a user to be able to edit the task priority by clicking the priority cell in the table which brings up a div where they can select a new priority which is then sent to the backend via ajax.

Currently it works fine but only the first time, once I reload the task table partial it's totally broken, I believe I have a scoping issue as it still detects clicks on the body but not on any of the elements within the reloaded partial but I can't figure it out.

```
var priorityUpdater;

priorityUpdater = function() {
  var pCells = document.getElementsByClassName('priority-cell');

  $('.task-table')[0].onscroll = function () {
    if ($('.priority-changer')[0]) {
      $('.priority-changer')[0].remove();
    }
  }

  document.body.onclick = function () {
    if ($('.priority-changer')[0]) {
      $('.priority-changer')[0].remove();
    }
  }

  for (var i=0; i < pCells.length; i++) {
    pCells[i].onclick = function (e) {
      if (!$('.priority-changer')[0]) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        var currentPriority = this.getElementsByClassName('red').length
        var taskId = this.id
        div.className = 'priority-changer';
        div.style.top = (this.getBoundingClientRect()['top'] + 2) + 'px';
        div.style.left = (this.getBoundingClientRect()['left'] + 20) + 'px';
        div.innerHTML = 
        '<label for="'+'task-'+taskId+'">Priority</label>' +
        '<select name="priority" id="'+'task-'+taskId+'">' +
          '<option value="1"'+ ((currentPriority === 1) ? 'selected' : '') + '>1</option>' +
          '<option value="2"'+ ((currentPriority === 2) ? 'selected' : '') + '>2</option>' +
          '<option value="3"'+ ((currentPriority === 3) ? 'selected' : '') + '>3</option>' +
          '<option value="4"'+ ((currentPriority === 4) ? 'selected' : '') + '>4</option>' +
          '<option value="5"'+ ((currentPriority === 5) ? 'selected' : '') + '>5</option>' +
        '</select>';
        e.target.appendChild(div);
        e.stopPropagation();

        $('.priority-changer')[0].onclick = function (e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
        };

        $('#task-'+taskId).change( function() {
          $.ajax({url:'/tasks', type: 'PATCH', data:{task: {id: taskId, priority: $(this).val()}}});
        });
      };
    };
  };
};

$(window).load(function() {
  return priorityUpdater();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was to do with turbolinks and was solved by delegating the click actions as seen in [Why would this JS fire on a form partial rendered on 1 page but not another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619731/why-would-this-js-fire-on-a-form-partial-rendered-on-1-page-but-not-another)